# Monge Array - leftmost minimum for each row

Tags: algorithm, rust, divide-and-conquer

This implementation is the result of solving exercise 4-6 "Monge Arrays" from the book Introduction to algorithms.

Definition of a Monge Array:

> An m x n array A of real numbers is a Monge array if for all \$i\$,
>   \$j\$, \$k\$, and \$l\$ such that \$1 \le i \lt k \le m\$ and \$1 \le j \lt l \le n\$, we have \$A[i, j] + A[k, l] \le A[i, l] + A[k, j]\$.
>
> Relevant parts of problem 4-6:
>
> d. Here is a description of a divide-and-conquer algorithm that
>   computes the left- most minimum element in each row of an m x n Monge
>   array A:
>
> Construct a submatrix A' of A consisting of the even-numbered rows of
>   A. Recursively determine the leftmost minimum for each row of A'. Then
>   compute the leftmost minimum in the odd-numbered rows of A. Explain
>   how to compute the leftmost minimum in the odd-numbered rows of A
>   (given that the leftmost minimum of the even-numbered rows is known)
>   in \$O(m + n)\$ time.
>
> e. Write the recurrence describing the running time of the algorithm
>   described in part (d). Show that its solution is \$O(m + nlog(m))\$.

I am especially interested in making my code more idiomatic and clean although any improvements to the algorithm are also welcome.

```
fn min(monge: &Vec<i32>, from: usize, to: usize) -> usize{

    let mut min = monge[from];

    (from + 1..to).fold(from, |m,i| {

        if(monge[i] < min){
            min = monge[i]; 
            i 
        } else{ m } 
    })
}


fn minimums(monge: &Vec<i32>, leftmost: & mut Vec<usize>, rows: usize, columns: usize, factor: usize)
{

    if rows == 1 {  
        leftmost[0] = min(monge, 0, columns) % columns;
    }
    else {

        let mid = rows - (rows / 2);
        minimums(monge, leftmost, mid, columns, 2 * factor);          

        let get = |i, j| (i * columns) + j;

        for row in (0..)
                       .map(|x| factor * (2 * x + 1))
                       .take_while(|&x| x < (rows - 1)) {

            leftmost[row] =  min(monge, 
                                 get(row ,leftmost[row - factor]), 
                                 get(row, leftmost[row + factor] + 1)) % columns; 
        }

        if rows % 2 == 0 {

            let row = factor * (rows - 1);
            leftmost[row] = min(monge,
                                get(row , leftmost[row - factor]),
                                get(row, columns)) % columns; 
        }

    }
}

fn main() {

    let row = 7;
    let x = vec!
    [10,17,13,28,23,
     17,22,16,29,23,
     24,28,22,34,24,
     11,13,6,17,7,
     45,44,32,37,23,
     36,33,19,21,6,
     75,66,51,53,34];

    let mut leftmost = vec![0;row];

    minimums(&x, &mut leftmost, row,5, 1);

    for x in leftmost { 
        println!("{}", x);    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read compiler warnings *and fix them*:

   ```
   src/main.rs:7:11: 7:27 warning: unnecessary parentheses around `if` condition, #[warn(unused_parens)] on by default
   src/main.rs:7         if(monge[i] < min){
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ```
2. Spaces before braces

   ```
   fn min(...) -> usize{ // No
   fn min(...) -> usize { // Yes
   ```
3. Be consistent about brace indentation

   ```
   // No
   if {
       1
   } else { 2 }

   // Yes
   if {
       1
   } else {
       2
   }
   ```
4. `mut` is stuck to the `&`

   ```
   & mut Vec<usize> // No
   &mut Vec<usize> // Yes
   ```
5. `else` lives on the same line as the previous curly brace

   ```
   // No
   if true {
       1
   }
   else {
       2
   }

   // Yes
   if true {
       1
   } else {
       2
   }
   ```
6. No need to leave blank space at the beginning of a block

   ```
   // No
   fn foo() {

       let a = 1;

   // Yes
   fn foo() {
       let a = 1;
   ```
7. Keep the macro braces attached to the macro name, and indent the body if it's going to be multiline. Leave a trailing comma, and use spaces after the comma

   ```
   let x = vec![
       10, 17, 13, 28, 23, 
       17, 22, 16, 29, 23, 
       24, 28, 22, 34, 24, 
       11, 13,  6, 17,  7, 
       45, 44, 32, 37, 23, 
       36, 33, 19, 21,  6, 
       75, 66, 51, 53, 34,
   ];
   ```
8. Leave spaces after commas in function calls as well, but not before

   ```
   // No
   get(row ,leftmost[row - factor]),

   // Yes
   get(row, leftmost[row - factor]),
   ```
9. A single space around `=`

   ```
   leftmost[row] =  min(...); // No
   leftmost[row] = min(...); // Yes
   ```
10. **Never** take a `&Vec<T>` as an argument, use a `&[T]` instead. This allows more types to be provided
11. Your `min` function is poorly named. The name seems to suggest it will return the minimum value, when it actually returns the *index* of the minimum value. Rename it to something intention-revealing. Maybe `index_of_minimum`
12. Space after a `;` in an array or vector

    ```
    vec![0;row]; // No
    vec![0; row]; // Yes
    ```
13. Instead of having multiple lines in a `for x in y` clause, create a variable to store that in.

    ```
    // Poor name because I'm not sure what it really is
    let x_rows = (0..)
        .map(|x| factor * (2 * x + 1))
        .take_while(|&x| x < (rows - 1));

    for row in x_rows {
    ```
14. Eventually, `min_by` will be stabilized, and you can use it:

    ```
    // May be off-by-one errors here
    let (min_index, _) =
        monge.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .skip(from)
        .take(to - from)
        .min_by(|&(_, v)| v)
        .unwrap();
    min_index
    ```

I'm sure there's more that can be suggested, but my brain is tired for now ^_^.

```
fn index_of_minimum(monge: &[i32], from: usize, to: usize) -> usize {
    let mut min = monge[from];

    (from + 1..to).fold(from, |m,i| {
        if monge[i] < min {
            min = monge[i];
            i
        } else {
            m
        }
    })
}

fn minimums(monge: &[i32], leftmost: &mut Vec<usize>, rows: usize, columns: usize, factor: usize) {
    if rows == 1 {
        leftmost[0] = index_of_minimum(monge, 0, columns) % columns;
    } else {
        let mid = rows - (rows / 2);
        minimums(monge, leftmost, mid, columns, 2 * factor);

        let get = |i, j| (i * columns) + j;

        let x_rows = (0..)
            .map(|x| factor * (2 * x + 1))
            .take_while(|&x| x < (rows - 1));

        for row in x_rows {
            leftmost[row] = index_of_minimum(monge,
                                get(row, leftmost[row - factor]),
                                get(row, leftmost[row + factor] + 1)) % columns;
        }

        if rows % 2 == 0 {
            let row = factor * (rows - 1);
            leftmost[row] = index_of_minimum(monge,
                                get(row, leftmost[row - factor]),
                                get(row, columns)) % columns;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let row = 7;
    let x = vec![
        10, 17, 13, 28, 23,
        17, 22, 16, 29, 23,
        24, 28, 22, 34, 24,
        11, 13,  6, 17,  7,
        45, 44, 32, 37, 23,
        36, 33, 19, 21,  6,
        75, 66, 51, 53, 34,
    ];

    let mut leftmost = vec![0; row];

    minimums(&x, &mut leftmost, row, 5, 1);

    for x in leftmost {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```